# How to create self-extracted exe C# .net 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, zip, self-extracting

I want to make single exe file that will extract a Folder with a lot of stuff inside.

I want this exe to work on computers with .net 4.0

I was trying to decompress embedded zip archive with the folder, but it is not simple with .net 4.0

Comment: If you by saying _"it is not simple with .net 4.0"_ are referring to that you cannot use the `ZipFile` class, I have something good to tell you: The `ZipFile` class is actually usable in .NET 4.0! You just have to import the `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` file, which is located somewhere in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL`. Try searching for it there, and when found just import it as a reference to your project and it'll work!

Comment: @Visual Vincent, The primary reference "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.IO.Compression.FileSystem" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.IO.Compression, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Comment: It works for me? I imported it from `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll`.

Comment: @VisualVincent, yes, i imported this file as a reference(right click on references->add reference->browse->choose). wtf, isn't 4.0 equal with 4.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes it is. But according to the error it sounds like the already existing `System.IO.Compression` namespace is the incorrect version... Are you sure you haven't accidentelly imported/referenced another version of it?

Comment: @VisualVincent, I am using

    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
and referencing Analyzer, Systems and System.IO.Compression.FileSystem

Also, it is not an error, it is a warning(in error list window). But there is an error "The name 'ZipFile' does not exist in the current context" (in output window)

Comment: Check your project's references to see if there's an invalid `System.IO.Compression` there.

Comment: References are ok, it works with .net 4.5, but not with 4.0

Comment: Maybe because it was included first in .NET 4.5? The reason it would work in 4.0 is that there's no .NET 4.5 specific code in the library (which apparently is the case, it has always worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do this by adding a .zip file to your C# installer project and setting its Build Action to "Embedded Resource."  Then, your C# installer program would extract that file from itself using [Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.getmanifestresourcestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), writing the contents of the stream to disk.

Comment: But how can I unzip it in .net 4.0?

Comment: I see from the comments on your question that the trouble you're having is finding a built-in zip/unzip library.  I don't know much about that, but you could certainly use a third-party library like [SharpZipLib](https://icsharpcode.github.io/SharpZipLib/) or a command-line program like [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).  (There's also a .NET wrapper for 7-Zip that allows you to link to the main DLL, but I haven't tried it.)

Comment: I prefer built-in, but I accept third-party. However, I am not sure I can create the situation that a single exe could use dll somehow

Comment: Yeah, a full-blown 7-Zip .exe might work best for you: make it and the 7z.dll both embedded resources, then when it's time to unpack, write both of them to disk along with the embedded .zip file, then use the .exe to unzip the .zip.  Kinda ugly, but it could work.

Comment: Excellent!  Glad to hear it.