# How to zip a folder in vb

Tags: arrays, vb.net, zip

I'm doing a project related to stenography. I need to hide multiple files inside a single image. I managed to bring all the files required to hide into a single folder. Now I need to zip this file and convert it to byte array so that I can pick bit by bit and hide it in LSB bit of an image.

How can I zip a folder in vb and convert it to byte array.
Also which compression mode should I use? Time is not a big factor for me, but I need the data exactly as before it was zipped. I must not loose a single bit.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.zipfile(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I tried ZipFile CreateFromDirectory, but it says ZipFile not declared.

Comment: YOu need to reference and import System.IO.Compression

Comment: I can't find System.IO.Compression in reference tab. I'm using vb 2010, Is it available in 2010

Comment: Select dot net framework 4.5

Comment: @Trevor : You can only use .NET 4.0 in VS2010.

Comment: @E.J : To use the `ZipFile` class in VS2010 you need to add a reference to the  `System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll` file, which is located in some sub-folder of: `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` - search for it there using Windows's search function and you should be able to find it.

Comment: [**In my case**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37058709/how-to-create-self-extracted-exe-c-sharp-net-4-0#comment61772833_37058709) the file can be found in `%SystemRoot%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.IO.Compr‌​ession.FileSystem\v4‌​.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c56‌​1934e089\System.IO.C‌​ompression.FileSyste‌​m.dll`

Comment: Reference was sucessfully added. When I tried to execute  

ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startPath, zipPath) 

Dim startPath As String = "C:\Users\Eldhose\Desktop\STEG\Source"

Dim zipPath As String = "C:\Users\Eldhose\Desktop\STEG\Dest\result.zip"

It says "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\Eldhose\Desktop\STEG\Dest\result.zip'.", How to automatically create it

Comment: `If Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipPath)) = False Then Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(zipPath))`

Comment: @visual Vincent Thanks